# How do I properly reconnect a Logitech MX Revolution?

Tags: connection, logitech-mouse

I have a new USB receiver for my Logitech MX Revolution mouse. Now, when I try to connect it using the connection utility it fails. I do exactly as told, but the mouse does not react.

I read on other forums that people have problems with this utility too. Is there a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't have the right receiver for the mouse. there are two types (2007, 2008) which are not compatible with each other.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a non unifying device.  You run the old connection utility.  Turn the mouse off hold one of the mouse buttons and click the other five times.  Then let go of the one you're holding down.

Comment: Although your answer might be correct, it lacks the proof. Do you have any references to support it?